# How to exclude a folder in S3 from Airflow's S3sensor?

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I've set up a bucket of tasks for my airflow job to pick up like so:

```
/bucket-of-tasks
    - task-2
    - task-3
    /completed
        - task-1
```

Is there a way to use S3Sensor and exclude keys that start with `completed/`? they only seem to offer a wildcard match. Here's example code that I've written:

```
    def check_for_emails(self):
        return S3KeySensor(
            task_id='check_for_emails',
            bucket_name='bucket_name',
            poke_interval= 60, # Try every  minute
            timeout= 60 * 5, # Timeout after 5 minutes, so 5 pokes on our bucket
            aws_conn='us_east_1',
            bucket_key="*Things_to_match*",
            wildcard_match=True,
            soft_fail=True,
            dag=self.dag
        )
```

Comment: I believe the answer is that there's no way to do it simply since the S3KeySensor uses fnmatch.fnmatch under the hood. The best thing to do is to create a /todo folder so I can have todo/*things_to_match*

Answer (score 1):

S3KeySensor's wildcard matching uses fnmatch.fnmatch under the hood, so there's no easy way to do this.